# In Bumblebee, how did Charlie's use of an electroshock weapon work?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, bumblebee-2018

Near the end of the movie, Charlie shocks Bumblebee several times with some sort of electroshock weapon, but I don't understand how (in universe) this could have resuscitated him.

How did the electroshock weapon resuscitate Bumblebee?

Comment: It was used as some form of defibrillator I’d imagine.